# Can we split a Big HDFS Folder?

Tags: shell, hadoop, split, hdfs, bigdata

I have a hdfs folder sized around 570 TB, there are number of sub folders and I wanted to split one of the sub folder which is of around 530 TB.

Comment: What do you mean by split? Does this sub-folder contains only files? How many files are present? How many of these files, you want to move to some other folder? Hadoop does not have any split command.

Comment: Thanks Manjunath for the reply, I meant Splitting of a sub folder from the hdfs parent folder which is in big size consists of hive warehouse and I want make this warehouse folder has separate hdfs parent folder. Yes Hadoop does not have split command. Can we write any script to split it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hadoop fs -mv` (Move) command to achieve the same.

For e.g. let's assume, you have following folder structure:

```
/tmp/1GB/
/tmp/2GB/
/tmp/3GB/
```

Now, you want to split `/2GB/` from `/tmp/` and move it under `/` (root folder).

All you have to do is:

`hadoop fs -mv /tmp/2GB /`

Now the folder structure will be:

```
/2GB/
/tmp/1GB/
/tmp/3GB/
```

Also, since `move` is just a meta data operation, it is not costly to execute it, as opposed to `copy` operation.